# Sorting in the ascending and then in the descending order in Python without negation

Tags: python, sorting

I have this list:

```
L = [(1, 'a'), (4, 'k'), (3, 'p'), (3, 'q'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'z')]
```

which I want to sort in the ascending order by the 0th element of each tuple and *then* in the descending order by the 1st one. What's the way to do that?

I could use the general approach:

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

but it's impossible because there's no `-` operation for strings.

How should I call `sort` to get what I need?

Comment: Reverse the whole sort and make the _number_ negative? Assuming you want `[(1, 'z'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'q'), (3, 'p'), (4, 'k')]`.

Comment: A simple solution to make your key function work would be to use [ord](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to convert the letters to ints - `L.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -ord(x[1])))`

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but that looks like a trick. What if both x[0] and x[1] in each tuple were characters (strings)? I wouldn't be able to do that 'negative' trick.

Comment: @IainShelvington Sure, but I have the same question I asked jonrsharpe: What if I had only strings and weren't able to use ord or negative?

Comment: Are the tuples **always** comprised of an integer a single-character string?

Comment: Well, _is_ that your case? Use a more representative example. In more general cases note the effective key of a string is `[ord(c) for c in s]`.

Comment: subclass `str` and implement `__neg__` accordingly. Remember that _string literals_ will not be affected by a global statement such as `str = MyStr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because TimSort (algorithm used by `.sort()` and `sorted()`) is a "*stable*" sorting algorithm, you can first sort the list by the second priority and then once again sort it by your first priority.

```py
L = [(1, "a"), (4, "k"), (3, "p"), (3, "q"), (2, "a"), (2, "b"), (1, "z")]
L.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
L.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print(L)
```

It might be slightly slower than other methods (using tuple and `ord` function) but it exists.

Answer (score 0):

With first element sorted:

```
def f(x):
    return x[0]
L.sort(key=f)
```

With second element reverse sorted:

```
def f1(x):
    return x[1]
L.sort(key=f1, reverse=True)
```